# how to programmatically link resources in azure cloud services?

Tags: azure

Please let me know is there any way to programmatic-ally link the resources(sql database or storage account) to my Azure cloud service.

Comment: Are you referring to the Linked resources you see in the portal?

Answer (score 0):

This is a vague question, but... Windows Azure SQL Database and Windows Azure Storage are both services you simply *consume* - grab an endpoint and connect. That's the link. Very loose coupling. For SQL Database, it's just like accessing an on-premises database: open a connection via connection string and start working with the database.

For Windows Azure Storage, you can connect to any storage account you create, even ones in different subscriptions, as long as you have the account name and access key.

If there's something more specific you're looking for, you'll need to post a more specific question.